# How can i do a backup system between my mongoDB database hosted in my server and my SQLite database hosted in my remote device?

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, cloud, iot

I have a server where hosted my main db in MongoDB. This DB receive data from a IoT device througth MQTT protocol each secound.

When my IoT device loses the internet connection, begins to register the data into a local SQLite DB.

When the internet connection on my IoT device is restablished, it send to my server all the SQLite files created until this point.

My server receive all of this SQLite files in a folder.

So, at this point, i dont know how is the better way to inject all the SQLite files received into my MongoDB main DB.

Can you expose some ideas for get in my MongoDB all of there SQLite data?
there is a better way for recover this data? (i am thinking in a cloud services or something like this)

Comment: Can you replay the data from the sql databases rather than sending the files? You already have an ingestion process.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion Matt. I will evaluate it between my choises.